# I got this problem with the implementations in build gradle , what should I do please?

Tags: java, android

What went wrong:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not find androidx.core: core-ktx: 1.0.1.
 Searched in the following locations:
   - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/core/ core-ktx/ 1.0.1/ core-ktx- 1.0.1.pom
   - https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/core/ core-ktx/ 1.0.1/ core-ktx- 1.0.1.pom
   - https://jitpack.io/androidx/core/ core-ktx/ 1.0.1/ core-ktx- 1.0.1.pom
   - https://maven.google.com/androidx/core/ core-ktx/ 1.0.1/ core-ktx- 1.0.1.pom
 Required by:
     project :app
Could not find androidx.appcompat: appcompat: 1.0.2.
 Searched in the following locations:
   - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/appcompat/ appcompat/ 1.0.2/ appcompat- 1.0.2.pom
   - https://jcenter.bintray.com/androidx/appcompat/ appcompat/ 1.0.2/ appcompat- 1.0.2.pom
   - https://jitpack.io/androidx/appcompat/ appcompat/ 1.0.2/ appcompat- 1.0.2.pom
   - https://maven.google.com/androidx/appcompat/ appcompat/ 1.0.2/ appcompat- 1.0.2.pom
  Required by:
```

Comment: Which version of Android Studio are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You have extra spaces in your build.gradle file. `androidx.core: core-ktx: 1.0.1` needs to be `androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.1` and `androidx.appcompat: appcompat: 1.0.2` needs to be `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2`.